# Angular missing method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Im currently building an angular application that has a C# backend that expose services. I want to use angularjs resources to access those services. When in the controller I call the resource I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function g(b){z(b||{},this)} has no method 'getCourse'
    at new <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:81/ClientApp/controllers/CourseIndex.js:6:36)
    at d (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:30:352)
    at Object.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:30:482)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:59:495
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:47:450
    at p (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:7:367)
    at U (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:47:342)
    at k (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:42:309)
    at k (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:42:326)
    at http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:41:371
```

Here is my controller:

```
coursewareApp.controller('CourseIndex', function ($scope, $location, Courses) {
    $scope.courseOutline = Courses.getCourse(); //Error in this line
    $scope.courseOutline.then(
        function(course) {
            $scope.courseOutline = fixFormat(course);
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Here is my service:

```
coursewareApp.factory('Courses', function ($resource, $q) {
    var resource = $resource('/api/Block', {},
                    {
                        getCourse: {
                            method: 'GET',
                            headers: { 'Authorization-Token': '6A594741380806DF128E28BDCC072859A1ECF0DC24478DDD890CC191C8357AFF12F837F657104E285BE8E2151F8631D148DEF89420024EDAA71DDB8404A1C1947ABD2BBE8002952DC891246CADCB1D452F445E773AB0CE8B4B9CF566A738ED7736AFC66B61FBFDCD59EDD68D2F8F4D5FF31DA0DD8F0CA98C10CA07F18C1C386462D0D2694385DA38C9F6C2A04B15B885AEBDF917E155014942040272E0F36B2D4E39303CBC430738902CF75093EAD11492AA87A9' },
                            url: '/api/Block/Courses',
                        }
                    });
    return {
        getCourse: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            resource.getCourse(
                function(event) {
                    deferred.resolve(event);
                },
                function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

I have read many solutions to similar problems but none of them seem to apply to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Can you check this fiddle and see if there's something different:  http://jsfiddle.net/N4zJv/1/

Comment: Looks like it is the same except for the mock..

Comment: Is you script `CourseIndex.js` minified?

Comment: no, its running on debug in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a minification issue try to declare you controllers\services in minification friendly manner

```
coursewareApp.controller('CourseIndex', ['$scope', '$location', 'Courses',function ($scope, $location, Courses) {
}]);


coursewareApp.factory('Courses', ['$resource','$q',function ($resource, $q) {

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately this isn't the problem. Updated declarations and still getting the same error.